# Intuition on why quantum hall effect?

Tags: electrons, quantum-hall-effect

I think I can understand hall effect using  the right hand rule, the electrons experience lorentz force in the presence of a magnetic field but I don't get why quantum? I saw the resistivity looks like a stepped graph why do electrons behave in such a manner like a current flowing through a multi stages zener diode? (OK I made up the multi stages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest explanation requires basic knowledge about *quantum point contacts*. QPCs are narrow openings between two electron gases, where transverse motion of electrons is quantized. The conductance through such openings is guantized in the units of the *conductance quantum*
$$G_0 = \frac{2e^2}{h}.$$
This happens, because for a one-dimensional motion the group velocity exactly cancels out with the density of states (the former is proportional to $\partial_k\epsilon(k)$, whereas the latter is inversely proportional to this quantity). The conductance is therefore proportional to the number of conducting transverse energy levels, each level contributing  $G_0$. More formally this physics is expressed by the [Landauer formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer_formula).

In quantum Hall effect the magnetic field is so strong that the electrons are confined to the walls of the conductor, moving in effectively one-dimensional channels, and thus exhibiting conductance quantization (which means that the resistance scales as $1/n$ with the number of conducting sub-bands.)

What I described here is the *Integer quantum Hall effect* (IQHE), which is essentially a one-particle phenomenon. *Fractional quantum Hall effect* has to do with electron-electron interactions and by far more complex.