# Edge mode currents in quantum hall effect

Tags: solid-state-physics, quantum-hall-effect

In David Tong's notes on the quantum hall effect, when calculating the current due to edge modes, he writes it's expression as
$$I_y = -e \int \frac{dk}{2 \pi} v_y(k)$$
where $v_y$ is the drift velocity of the state with momentum $\hbar k$. But I fail to understand how that gives the current. And why is there a factor of $2 \pi$ in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $2\pi$is there because when you have a an edge with lenth $L$ the allowed values of $k$ are $k_n= 2\pi n/L$. So as $L$ becomes large we have
$$
dk =  \frac{2\pi}{L} dn
$$
and so
$$
\sum_{n}  f(k_n) \approx  \int f(k_n) dn \to  L \int \frac{dk}{2\pi} f(k)
$$
The $L$ drops out because to get the current you need to multiply the drift velocity $v$ by the charge *density*  which is
$$
\rho = \frac 1 L \sum_n \theta(k_f-k_n)\to \int_{k<k_f} \frac{dk}{2\pi}
$$

Comment: There is no group velocity in your answer.

Comment: @Roger Vadim: I think the OP knows that $J=\rho v_{\rm drift}$. It was  the $\rho$ that was confusing him.

Comment: This is not drift, but coherent transport: $\int dk v(k) \int dk \rho(k) \neq \int dk v(k)\rho(k)$

Answer (score 2):

Current in a crystalline solid can be expressed as
$$
\mathbf{j}\propto \int_{\text{BZ}}\mathbf{v}_g(\mathbf{k})n(\mathbf{k})d^3\mathbf{k},
$$
i.e., a product of electron group velocity in a state, times the occupation number of this state, summed over all the states (the proof can be found in solid state physics texts, but see also [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/692670/247642) for more discussion).

At zero temperature the distribution function is a step function, i.e., it merely defines the limit of integration:
$$
\mathbf{j}\propto \int_0^{k_F} v_g(k)dk = \int_0^{\epsilon_F} v_g(E)\rho(E)dE,
$$
Further it can be shown that in 1D the density of states is inversely proportional to the group velocity and the two cancel out. This is the core of the integer quantum Hall effect as well as conductance quantization in 1D structures.

See [Landauer formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer_formula), [Conductance quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductance_quantum), and [Intuition on why quantum hall effect?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/569175/247642).